Parsing unindented nested list: Are all types of list allowed as a sublist?
I am trying to parse a nested list into a tree. What makes it difficult is that the text is unindented, so I wonder if there are rules I can rely on.
1.
  a)
    i)
      1)

Usually, I see number -> letter -> roman numeral. Would something like the following examples be allowed/valid?
1.
  i)
    a)

1.
  i) 
    A)

(capital letter sub-list of roman numeral)
A)
  A)
    1.
      1.

("A" child of same type of list "A")
• 
  1.
  2.
•
  1.

(1. child of bullet point)
1.
  A)
    i)
  B)
    a.

("i)" and "a." are different types of lists)
I wasn't able to find rules/guidelines on this topic. (Is there a better place to ask?)

Paragraph numbering is totally domain specific. Legal, engineering, scientific etc. docs are all likely to have their own conventions. Coming up with a parser that correctly recognizes all possible standards will be heuristic and error prone. One easy example is that i) could mean "letter i" or "Roman numeral 1".  So its indentation level is ambiguous.
